# Unity UI button not working

Tags: unity, 3d, gui, unity-ui

I'm creating a game in unity and I can't get the UI buttons to work. Here is what I tried:

- Added a graphics raycaster to the canvas
- Added an events system with an Input System UI Input Manager
- Checked that nothing is blocking the buttons

This is in a pause menu, when the time scale is 0.

Here is the hierarchy:
[image]

Comment: We don't have enough information here to diagnose the problem. We currently can't see the configuration of your event system, raycaster, or input module, nor the inspector parameters of the buttons in question. Do any logs, warnings, or errors print in the debug console when you run or try to click these buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed the problem, I was using the new Input System UI Input Manager instead of Standalone Input Module

Answer (score 0):

Check if Raycast Target is on in order to click, and off for being unclickable.
More advice: just enable inside the button background and disables it inside the text, optimizing your game.